# Body of PUT & POST unknown

Tags: json, rest, post, google-cloud-firestore, put

I have been given an assignment, has a permissions endoint. This returns a list of enpoints I can use. As you can see below, two of them at PUT & POST. No where in the assignment does it stipulate what the body of these calls should be.

**Question**

Is there any way for me to determine what the body should be?

I haven't been given more information. Am I missing something obvious?

**Example**

```
GET https://endpoint.com/@{xxx}/permissions
```

Which returns:

```
{
    "continents": {
        "order": 2,
        "actions": {
            "show": true
        },
        "children": {}
    },
    "car manufacturers": {
        "order": 3,
        "actions": {
            "show": true
        },
        "children": {}
    },
    "products": {
        "order": 1,
        "actions": {
            "show": true,
            "getItems": {
                "type": "GET",
                "URL": "https://endpoint.com/@{xxx}/products"
            },
            "updateItem": {
                "type": "PUT",
                "URL": "https://endpoint.com/@{xxx}/products/{id}"
            },
            "addItem": {
                "type": "POST",
                "URL": "https://endpoint.com/@{xxx}/products"
            }
        },
        "slug": "/products/",
        "children": {}
    }
}
```

If I try a random JSON body, e.g:

```
POST https://endpoint.com/@{richardmarais}/products
```

I get:

```
{
    "code": 500,
    "error": "Invalid use of type \"undefined\" as a Firestore argument."
}
```

Comment: Perform the GET request to get your model for the other calls.

Comment: Thanks.  I try the GET to get the model, but it just returns an empty list.